AWS API GATEWAY: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
We have an AWS Gateway API to fetch (GET) data which is working in the current production setup. While developing a new external module I'm running into the issue "Origin "http://localhost:8080" is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 400"
The flow:

Client
Method request
Integration request
4.Lambda integration
5.Integration response (proxy integration)
Method response

How/where should I add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in AWS?
Should I allow everything?
The API is secured with an API key and JWT authentication barrier.
In the AWS API Gateway GET resource I have added a method response with Status 200 and header name "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".
In the OPTIONS I have added header mappings in the integration response:
method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers ''
method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'
method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin ''
The method responses has:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Default 4XX Gateway response also has the above headers with a "*"
